# Print two different results from a directory search and filter using AWK

Tags: bash, awk, find

I'm trying to match and print two results from a directory search and filter using AWK. My directory containts a number of Terraform files, and I'm trying to find the provider and version of each.

Here are two totally different examples, which it may or may not look exactly like for the others;

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version         = "=1.44.0"
  client_id       = var.ARM_CLIENT_ID
  client_secret   = var.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
  subscription_id = var.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
  tenant_id       = var.ARM_TENANT_ID
}
```

or

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  version         = "<= 2.33"
  client_id       = var.ARM_CLIENT_ID
  client_secret   = var.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
  subscription_id = var.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
  tenant_id       = var.ARM_TENANT_ID

  skip_provider_registration  = true
  skip_credentials_validation = true
}
```

I can use the `find` command and print out all the files that contain that by using a 'between' search;
`find . -name "*.tf" -exec awk '/^provider/,/^}/' {} +`

An example of that output (many pages long), looks like this;

```
provider "azurerm" {
    version         = "<= 1.40"
    client_id       = var.ARM_CLIENT_ID
    client_secret   = var.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
    subscription_id = var.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    tenant_id       = var.ARM_TENANT_ID
}
provider "azurerm" {
    version           = "=2.34.0"
    features {}
    client_id         = var.ARM_CLIENT_ID
    client_secret     = var.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
    subscription_id   = var.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    tenant_id         = var.ARM_TENANT_ID
}
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
    version         = "2.2"
    alias           = "prd"
    client_id       = var.ARM_CLIENT_ID
    client_secret   = var.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
    subscription_id = var.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    tenant_id       = var.ARM_TENANT_ID
}
```

Using the following command I can print out just the versions of each one;
`find . -name "*.tf" -exec awk '/^provider/,/^}/' {} + | awk '$1 ~ /^version[[:space:]]*/ { for (i=2; i<NF; i++) gsub("\"",""); print $NF }'`

Where the results look like this;

```
2.2
1.44
=1.42
=1.42
1.41
=1.38.0
=1.42
>2.0.0
```

Using the following command, I can print out the provider name of each one;
`find . -name "*.tf" -exec awk '/^provider/,/^}/' {} + | awk '$1 ~ /^provider/ { gsub("\"",""); print $2}'`

Where the results look like this;

```
azurerm
panos
azurerm
azurerm
external
azurerm
azurerm
panos
```

Now I'm having trouble trying to find out how to combine them both together so that they can look something like;
`azurerm = 2.2`,
or even

```
azurerm
2.2
```

Basically anything that can bring them closer together so I can print out the providers/versions. A directory name print would be a massive bonus, too.

Any help on combining these two AWK commands woul be appreciated, as I've been trying to figure out how I can use the regex search with print of two different key/values in the same output. (`&&, ||, ...`)`

**EDIT**
Just to add to the answer given below by Markp, I manged to wrap it around a `for` block so it can print out the folder names they reside in;

```
for i in $( find . -name "*.tf" -execdir sh -c 'pwd' sh {} + | uniq); do
    cd "$i" || exit
    printf '\n\\%s\n' "${PWD##*/} contains:"
    find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.tf" -exec awk '/^provider/,/^}/' {} + | awk -F'"' '/^provider/ { pr=$2 ; next } /version/ { printf "%s %s\n", pr, $2 }'
done
```

...just thought someone else might find this handy

Comment: could you update your sections of sample output to match the 3x provider blocks in your initial `find` output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample input (generated by the initial `find/awk` call):

```
$ cat provider.dat
provider "azurerm" {
    version         = "<= 1.40"
    client_id       = var.ARM_CLIENT_ID
    client_secret   = var.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
    subscription_id = var.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    tenant_id       = var.ARM_TENANT_ID
}
provider "azurerm" {
    version           = "=2.34.0"
    features {}
    client_id         = var.ARM_CLIENT_ID
    client_secret     = var.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
    subscription_id   = var.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    tenant_id         = var.ARM_TENANT_ID
}
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
    version         = "2.2"
    alias           = "prd"
    client_id       = var.ARM_CLIENT_ID
    client_secret   = var.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
    subscription_id = var.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    tenant_id       = var.ARM_TENANT_ID
}
```

A single `awk` call to parse and print `<provider> \n <version>`:

```
awk -F'"' '                                   # use double quotes as input field separator
/^provider/ { pr=$2 ; next }                  # if lines starts with "provider" then save field 2 for later use
/version/   { printf "%s\n%s\n", pr, $2 }     # if line includes string "version" then print out the provider (pr) and version (field 2 from this line)
' provider.dat
```

The above generates:

```
azurerm
<= 1.40
azurerm
=2.34.0
azurerm
2.2
```

**NOTE**: May need to come back and tweak code depending on the final output format the OP is looking for.

---

**Assuming** the `provider` and `version` strings only show up in the blocks of data the OP wants, I'm wondering if the proposed answer (above) could be swapped out for the OP's current `awk` (fed by the `find`).

Regardless, I'm thinking it's probably possible to collapse all of the needed code into a single `awk` call (fed by the `find`), which may require some additional details re: sample input ...

Comment: Nice one @markp-fuso; I added that to my `find .` command and came up with this for a proper search/print function of all subfolders; `find . -name "*.tf" -exec awk '/^provider/,/^}/' {} + | awk -F'"' '/^provider/ { pr=$2 ; next } /version/ { printf "%s %s\n", pr, $2 }'`  I forgot about using variables and next as a placeholder!

Answer (score 0):

sed alternative:

```
sed -En 's/(^provider ")(.*)(".*$)/\2/p;s/(^.*version.*")(.*)("$)/\2/p' provider.dat
```

Split the provider line in three sections based on regular expressions and substitute the line for just the second part and printing. Split lines with version into 2 sections, substituting the line for the second section and printing.